# How can I map iOS or android appID to facebook appID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Facebook ads api requires FB Appid to create any ad with an objective of "mobile_app_install". Is there a way to map iOS appid or android appid to Facebook appid or is there a way of creating such ads without the facebook appid?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why would anyone vote this question -1?

Comment: You ask the person that wrote the app which Facebook App ID they put it in.

Comment: @WizKid facebook assigns an ID for each app. and they do have a mechanism to map iOS and android id to facebook appid. But it is not available in the API as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to run ads for your mobile app (on the app store or google play) without setting up a Facebook app. You need to run them as link ads - where the link you want people to click is some direct link into the app store, etc. However, the question is why do you want to do this?